# How to link static files in Gramex sub folder URL properly

Tags: templates, tornado, gramex

Created a tornado template `template.html` like so:

```html
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      {% set base = '.' %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.scss" />
    </head>
```

And in my `gramex.yaml` I have

```yaml
    url:
    ​  endpoint:
        pattern: /$YAMLURL/tmpl/?([^/]*)?/?([0-9]+)?
        handler: FileHandler
        kwargs:
          path: $YAMLPATH/template.html
          template: true
```

Now running gramex and trying to access the page.

when I access `http://localhost:9988/tmpl`, IT works fine and the `SCSS` is linked.
However accessing `http://localhost:9988/tmpl/1` or `http://localhost:9988/tmpl/1/1` tries to get the `SCSS` from `.../tmp/style.scss` and `.../tmp/1/style.scss` respectivelly.
I am sure that I am missing something very small.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

### PS - One solution is to use absolute paths like

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.scss" />`
However, that is not preferable.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible solutions:

1. Use `static_url`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url('style.css') }}" />
```

and keep `style.scss` in `<project_root>/static/style.scss`

2. Change `base` and use it

```html
  {% set base = '/' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ base }}style.css" />
```

> Not sure if those are best practices, but they work.

Comment: I generally use approach #2. I find it the simplest. Another option is to count the number of `/` characters in `handler.request.uri` and use `"../" * count` as the prefix.